# jquery lightbox popup with cookie

Tags: jquery, popup

im trying to make a lightbox popup that triggers is the user has not been to the site before telling them about a offer ... like the one here http://www.made.com/ (if youve been there befor you need to clear your cookies )

any way id like to do it using the fancybox lightbox as im using it on my page else where already, i was trying to figure it out from here http://www.veign.com/blog/2008/05/22/create-a-one-time-popup-using-jquery/ but the link to the jquery cookie libary is down.

any idea on where i can find a replacment / is this the best way to do it ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the utility functions at the bottom of this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html (createCookie and readCookie)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (readCookie("hasVisitedBefore") == null){
     //code to create popup here
  }
  createCookie("hasVisitedBefore", "true");
});
```

This will set a cookie using javascript when the user loads the page. If the cookie wasn't set when they arrived then you can launch your normal popup code.

Comment: is this cookie using javascript or jquery ? fancybox is a jquery lightbox will it work with it ?